# use different arrays for each workers instead of SharedArrays in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have a function like this:

@everywhere function bellman_operator!(rbc::RBC)

```
    ...
    @sync @parallel for i = 1:m
        ....
        for j = 1:n
            v_max = -1000.0
            ...
                for l = Next : n
                    ......
                    if v > vmax
                        vmax = v
                        Next = l
                    else
                        break 
                    end

                end
                f_v[j, i] = vmax
                f_p[j, i] = k
          end
    end
```

end

`f_v` and `f_p` are sharedArrays, I want to give different arrays for result of each workers, I saw some sample but I can't fix it.How can I use arrays for result of each workers and finally combine the results instead of using SharedArrays?

Comment: Could you please post a full and working code so that it can be copy pasted and indicate exactly what problem you have in this code. It is hard to help you if we do not understand: a) what exactly is your problem, b) what you have tried and why it failed. I am writing below what I think you want, but it is just guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Example 1. Combining results using `+`:

```
a = @parallel (+) for i in 1:1000
    rand(10, 10)
end
```

Example 2. Just collecting the results without combining them:

```
x = Future[]
for i in 1:1000
    push!(x, @spawn rand(10,10))
end
y = fetch.(x)
```